# Show all tasks of all subsites in my home page under one "All Tasks list" in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

How to show all tasks of all subsites in my home page under one "All Tasks list" in sharepoint 2010 ?
The admin at home page wants to see all tasks in all subsites under one list created at home page as "All tasks list"
Kindly Help !

Answer (score 0):

Best is to centralize all tasks in one list and share list view in all sub sites.

Follow below steps:

> 1. Create task list in site collection.
> 2. Generate data view webpart of task list using SP Designer and save it to site gallery.
> 3. Go to sub site. Edit page and add task list data view webpart found
>      in Miscellaneous category and save page.
> 4. Edit page again. Edit webpart property. Click on Edit the current
>      view link from List Views section.
> 5. Filter with Created By = [Me] and save view.

In sub site, user can see own tasks. But in site collections, all tasks are displayed in list.